# Getting Active Directory parameters for both: Windows Server 2008 and Linux Server

Tags: linux, windows, active-directory, domain, samba4

How do I get the values of the following parameters:

- DNS domain name
- NetBIOS domain name
- Kerberos realm
- LDAP base DN

For both:

- `Windows Server 2008 R2 (64-bit)` with an `Active Directory` configured
- `Linux Server` with an `Active Directory` configured (using Samba4)

Thanks.

Comment: The Windows part of the question is off-topic here at U&L...

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your Linux System is still an Univention Corporate Server. Most of your questions can be answered by reading our Documentation. You can easily find these things in the UMC UI.
Execute the following commands on your Linux Server to get them on console.

---

**DNS Domain Name:**

```
# ucr get domainname
```

---

**NetBIOS Domain Name:**

```
# ucr get windows/domain
```

NOTE: Used in Samba 3, Samba 4 predominantly uses the DNS/Kerberos domainname

---

**[3.7. Kerberos:](https://docs.software-univention.de/manual-4.2.html#domain:kerberos)**

> [...] The name of the Kerberos realm is configured as part of the installation of the master domain controller and stored in the Univention Configuration Registry variable kerberos/realm. [...]

```
# ucr get kerberos/realm
```

---

**LDAP Domain Name:**

```
# ucr get ldap/base
```

---

As I said before, it would be better to ask these software questions in the forum of the company developing it. In this case Univention.

Comment: and what about `Windows Server 2008 R2 (64-bit)`, how do I get this information there?

Comment: You should be able to find these in Microsofts programs. For example: Start > Programs > Administrative Tools > Active Directory Domains and Trusts.